# AJAX Post - One variable is not being sent properly

Tags: php, ajax

I have four variables I'm trying to pass via AJAX to be processed by some PHP on the same page: newJudgeName, newJudgeSection, newJudgeStatus, and originalJudgeName. The success function echos them out and they're the correct values, it's just the newJudgeStatus variable is not being picked up by my PHP. I've switched newJudgeStatus with newJudgeName in the data line on the AJAX request and then the value is sent just fine (I can see it in the db under Judge Name)... it's only when it's in the original spot in the ajax request that it doesn't work. I'm completely new to Ajax. Any help would be much appreciated.

AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",   
        url: "test.php",   
        data: 'newJudgeName=' + newJudgeName + '&newJudgeSection=' + newJudgeSection + '&newJudgeStatus =' + newJudgeStatus + '&originalJudgeName=' + originalJudgeName,
        success: function(){
            alert('newJudgeName=' + newJudgeName + '&newJudgeSection=' + newJudgeSection + '&newJudgeStatus =' + newJudgeStatus +'&originalJudgeName=' + originalJudgeName);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['newJudgeName'])){
        $newJudgeName = $_POST['newJudgeName'];
        $newJudgeSection = $_POST['newJudgeSection'];
        $newJudgeStatus = $_POST['newJudgeStatus'];
        $originalJudgeName = $_POST['originalJudgeName'];
        $judgeID = judgeNametoID($originalJudgeName);
        $con = mysql_connect("-","-","-");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        else {
            // connected to database successfully
        }
                    mysql_select_db("cm", $con);
        $query = ("UPDATE `casemanagers`.`judges` SET `Name`='$newJudgeName' , `Section`='$newJudgeSection', `Active`='$newJudgeStatus' WHERE `judgeID`='$judgeID';");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Please call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all of your `$_POST` vars in PHP. They're vulnerable to SQL injection right now:  `$originalJudgeName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['originalJudgeName']);`

Comment: Thanks--I'll be sure to do that before it's deployed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an errant space in your data string:

```
'&newJudgeStatus =' + newJudgeStatus +
---------------^^^^

// Should be
'&newJudgeStatus=' + newJudgeStatus +
```

Comment: Ha! I can't believe I spent an hour scrutinizing every line and missed that. Wow. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should send the data this way:

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: "test.php",   
    data: {
        'newJudgeName' : newJudgeName,
        'newJudgeSection' : newJudgeSection,
        'newJudgeStatus' : newJudgeStatus,
        'originalJudgeName' : originalJudgeName
    },
    success: function(){
        alert('newJudgeName=' + newJudgeName + '&newJudgeSection=' + newJudgeSection + '&newJudgeStatus =' + newJudgeStatus +'&originalJudgeName=' + originalJudgeName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manual processing, I'll recommend to put all these inside a form & use following code to send data:

```
$('#id_of_the_form').serialize();
```

instead of buggy:

```
newJudgeName=' + newJudgeName + '&newJudgeSection=' + newJudgeSection + '&newJudgeStatus =' + newJudgeStatus +'&originalJudgeName=' + originalJudgeName ...
```

See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/